# VBA code help opening file with differnt name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro i made and can't seem to get it to work correctly. 
If i run the macro and pick a file in a folder with multiple files of the same type. 
it only opens the first file in the folder. know matter what file i try to open, it will re-open the same file. for example. if i have 3 files with the names
cycle0001 , cycle0002, cycle0003 when ever i try to open file 003 it opens file 001 always. the code works great except i can't open the file i would like. 
only the file with the lowest number in the name.

Here is my code.

```
Sub jsonDataExtractor()
'
' jsonDataExtractor Macro
' Json Data Extractor
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'

File = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:=" (*.json), *.json", _
Title:="Select a file or files", _
MultiSelect:=True)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Workbooks.OpenText filename:= _
"cycle*.json", StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, _
Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 9), _
Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, most of it likely irrelevant. Could you try retyping the code which solely relates to your issue? Doing this will either highlight the issue for you as you go through it, or at least it will make it easier for others to help you. Identify where the code gives you a value other than what you would expect.

Comment: Sorry, here you go..

Comment: What happens if you change `cycle000*` to `cycle0002`?

Comment: if i change the file name, to a lower number it then opens that file. it always opens the file with the lowest number.

Comment: i want to be able to open any file in the folder, not just the one with the lowest value in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Use code similar to this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub jsonDataExtractor()

    Dim selectedFile As Variant, itm As Variant

    selectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=" (*.json), *.json", _
                                               Title:="Select a file or files", _
                                               MultiSelect:=True)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If TypeName(selectedFile) <> "Boolean" Then
        For Each itm In selectedFile
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=itm, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                               TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                               ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
                               Tab:=True, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, _
                               Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=":", _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 9), _
                               Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Next
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

You need to use the result returned by Application.GetOpenFilename()

.

- If MultiSelect:=**True** it can return either

  1. a Boolean (False if the user canceled)
  2. or an array of variants (file names) even if the user selects only one file

.

- If MultiSelect:=**False** it can return either

  1. a Boolean (False if the user canceled)
  2. or the file name (including its full path)

Comment: thanks for the info, i get what i did wrong. thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: is there a way to do this so that the data from multiple files gets placed into one sheet or one workbook? right now when i run this code it makes individual files. it would be nice to have this create one file or at least open the files into the same workbook. i tried with a query but was unsuccessful

Comment: I'm not sure what context you're running this in (what functions get called before or after) because this code doesn't generate the new files, but there are ways to 1. place the new data in separate sheets of the same workbook (create a new sheet for each imported text) 2. append the new text files in the same sheet (the new code will have to determine the number of rows imported, then open the next text file and place it in the next empty row). For either we'll need more context to modify current behavior so you should probably open a new question with relevant info